# Add two outcomes of a dice together python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm an absolute beginner to python but I really want to challenge myself. I want to create a game where a dice is rolled for each player (for now, two players) 2 times. The outcomes of the dice is added and if its even 10 points are added and if its odd, 5 points are subtracted. The players can play up to 5 rounds. So far, I've kept the code within a while loop and imported random to "roll" the dice but I don't know how to add the random outcomes together.

My code might be completely wrong but I would love some help and advice regarding how to fix it (this is done on python 3)

My code:

```
person1_name = input("What is your name: ")
person2_name = input("What is your name: ")

import random
number = random.randint(1,6)
rounds = "yes"
while rounds == "yes":
    print(person1_name, "- 1st roll = ",number, " and 2nd roll = ",number)
    total_1 = number + number
    if total_1 % 2 == 0:
        total_1 = total_1 + 10
        print(person1_name," has ",total_1, "points")
    else:
        total_1 = total_1 - 5
        print(person1_name, " has ",total_1, "points")
    print(person2_name, "- 1st roll = ",number, "and 2nd roll = ",number)
    total_2 = number + number
    if total_2 % 2 == 0:
        total_2 = total_2 + 10
        print(person2_name," has ",total_2, "points")
    else:
        total_2 = total_2 - 5
        print(person2_name," has ",total_2, "points")
    rounds = input("Do you want to play again (yes/no): ")
```

Comment: Your code only generates a single random number. You need to call `randint` inside the loop, and call it for each dice roll.

Comment: howmany dice you want to roll?

Comment: you only the dice rool it once!

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: Check my code below, for variable number of players and dice

Answer (score 3):

You may directly get the sum using [random.choices()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices).

```
sum_dices = sum(random.choices(range(1,7),k=2))
```

or directly check:

```
if sum(random.choices(range(1,7),k=2)) % 2:
     pass
else:
     pass
```

Comment: his code is more than just a sum thugh, this is wrong!

Comment: this answers the question, which according to the title is `Add two outcomes of a dice together`. I don't think debug all and provide working code is the best way to help OP.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, you need to call `random.randint()` to generate random numbers inside the loop. For keeping count of number of rounds, use another variable. Try this :

```
import random

person1_name = input("What is your name: ")
person2_name = input("What is your name: ")
rounds = "yes"
person1_tot, person2_tot = 0,0 ##
numround = 1 # Number of rounds
while rounds == "yes" and numround<=5:
    number1 = random.randint(1,6)
    number2 = random.randint(1,6)
    print(person1_name, "- 1st roll = ",number1, " and 2nd roll = ",number2)
    total_1 = number1 + number2
    if total_1 % 2 == 0:
        total_1 = total_1 + 10
        print(person1_name," has ",total_1, "points")
    else:
        total_1 = total_1 - 5
        print(person1_name, " has ",total_1, "points")
    person1_tot += total_1 ##
    print(person1_name, " : ", person1_tot) ##
    number1 = random.randint(1,6)
    number2 = random.randint(1,6)
    print(person2_name, "- 1st roll = ",number1, "and 2nd roll = ",number2)
    total_2 = number1 + number2
    if total_2 % 2 == 0:
        total_2 = total_2 + 10
        print(person2_name," has ",total_2, "points")
    else:
        total_2 = total_2 - 5
        print(person2_name," has ",total_2, "points")
    person2_tot += total_2 ##
    print(person2_name, " : ", person2_tot) ##
    numround+=1
    rounds = input("Do you want to play again (yes/no): ")
```

Comment: @ChelseaCookie Keep two other variables, say person1_total and person2_total. Initialize them to zero outside the loop. Update it whenever you calculate total_1 or total_2. Check updated code. (Marked with ##)

Answer (score 0):

you should pay attention to where you created the random number. In your code it is out of the loop meaning through out the whole session you would only produce one random number. I presumed you wanted to use two dies as well so that would mean you need another number variable.

```
import random

person1_name = input("What is your name: ")
person2_name = input("What is your name: ")

rounds = "yes"
while rounds == "yes":
    number, number2 = random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6)
    total_1 = number + number2
    print(person1_name, "- 1st roll = ",number, " and 2nd roll = ",number2)
    if total_1 % 2 == 0:
        total_1 = total_1 + 10
        print(person1_name," has ",total_1, "points")
    else:
        total_1 = total_1 - 5
        print(person1_name, " has ",total_1, "points")
    number, number2 = random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6)
    total_2 = number + number2
    print(person2_name, "- 1st roll = ",number, "and 2nd roll = ",number2)
    if total_2 % 2 == 0:
        total_2 = total_2 + 10
        print(person2_name," has ",total_2, "points")
    else:
        total_2 = total_2 - 5
        print(person2_name," has ",total_2, "points")
    rounds = input("Do you want to play again (yes/no): ")
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go with number of dice and number of players:

```
number_of_players = int(raw_input("Number of players: "))
number_of_dice = int(raw_input("Number of dice: "))
player_names = []
player_points = []
for i in range(number_of_players):
    name = raw_input("What is your name: ")
    player_names.append(name)
    player_points.append(0)

import random

def roll(number_of_dice=2):
    total = 0
    rolls = []
    for i in range(number_of_dice):
        dice = random.randint(1,6)
        print("dice "+str(i+1)+": "+str(dice))
        total += dice
        rolls.append(dice)
    return rolls,total
rounds = "yes"
while rounds == "yes":
    for i in range(number_of_players):

        print("rolling dice for "+player_names[i]+"....")
        rolls,total = roll(number_of_dice)
        if total % 2 == 0:
            player_points[i] += 10
        else:
            player_points[i] -= 5
        print(player_names[i]+" has "+str(player_points[i])+" points")
    rounds = raw_input("Do you want to play again (yes/no): ")
```

Comment: Why are you posting Python 2 code for a Python 3 question? BTW, it's bad style to bury imports in the middle of the script. Put them up the top, where they belong.